# How to solve 504 Timeout Error on Netlify and Vercel with MongoDB Connection in Next.js"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, netlify, vercel

Anytime my site is idle for a while, and I load it up, it shows a 504 timeout error from netlify and vercel. I'm aware this is due to the timeout limit set by both platforms, then on reload it works fine
I know this is due to the database connection, it takes a while to connect on initial connection

Is there a way to keep it connected always or how do you suggest I handle this in my next js project to prevent it from taking so long to connect after being idle for a while?

This is my db connect function

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGO_URL

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function db() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose
    })
  }

  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = null
    throw e
  }

  return cached.conn
}

export default db
```

and I call it this way: `await db()`
and this is how the db url looks like `mongodb+srv://*********@cluster0.7xbw7v5.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is caused by cold start, then a good fix would be to warmup the server with a periodic ping at your preferred time interval

I used checkly at https://www.checklyhq.com/

So you can create a separate endpoint for the warmup and checkly should run it at your set time interval